# Как осуществить перенаправление на главную страницу после выполнения асинхронного запроса с использованием redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Есть стор, есть компонент, жмякаем на кнопку в компоненте, диспачится экшн. Он ловится сагой-вочером. Назначенный вокер начинает делать axios.post запрос. Но мне нужно, чтобы после его выполнения вызвался метод, history.replace('/'). В каком месте это сделать?

Comment: axios возвращает промис, так что соответственно `axios.post(...).then(res => { 
history.replace('/') })`

Comment: я axios.post выполняю в саге, то есть в другом фале, то есть там негде взять history.  И выполняется это вот так `yield call(axios.post, 'url', data,  config).`

Comment: бросьте еще одно событие туда где есть history :) или импортируйте его в область видимости саги